# Optimising finding row pairs in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have a dataframe with rows that describe a movement of value between nodes in a system. This dataframe looks like this:

```
index   from_node   to_node  value  invoice_number
0       A           E        10     a
1       B           F        20     a
2       C           G        40     c
3       D           H        60     d
4       E           I        35     c
5       X           D        43     d
6       Y           F        50     d
7       E           H        70     a
8       B           A        55     b
9       X           B        33     a
```

I am looking to find "swaps" in the invoice history. A swap is defined where a node both receives and sends a value to a different node within the same invoice number. In the above dataset there are two swaps in invoice "a", and one swap in invoice "d" ("sent to" and "received from" could be the same node in the same row):

```
index   node    sent_to sent_value  received_from   received_value  invoice_number
0       B       F       20          X               33              a
1       E       H       70          A               10              a
2       D       H       60          X               43              d
```

I have solved this problem by iterating over all of the unique invoice numbers in the dataset and then iterating over each row within that invoice number to find pairs:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'from_node':['A','B','C','D','E','X','Y','E','B','X'],
    'to_node':['E','F','G','H','I','D','F','H','A','B'],
    'value':[10,20,40,60,35,43,50,70,55,33],
    'invoice_number':['a','a','c','d','c','d','d','a','b','a'],
    }) 

invoices = set(df.invoice_number)

list_df_swap = []
for invoice in invoices:
    df_inv = df[df.invoice_number.isin([invoice])]
    for r in df_inv.itertuples():
        df_is_swap = df_inv[df_inv.to_node.isin([r.from_node])]
        if len(df_is_swap.index) == 1:
            swap = {'node': r.from_node,
                    'sent_to': r.to_node,
                    'sent_value': r.value,
                    'received_from': df_is_swap.iloc[0]['from_node'],
                    'received_value': df_is_swap.iloc[0]['value'],
                    'invoice_number': r.invoice_number
                    }
            list_df_swap.append(pd.DataFrame(swap, index = [0]))
        
df_swap = pd.concat(list_df_swap, ignore_index = True)
```

The total dataset consists of several hundred million rows, and this approach is not very efficient. Is there a way to solve this problem using some kind of vectorised solution, or another method that would speed up the execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate all possible swaps, regradless of the invoice number:

```
swaps = df.merge(df, left_on='from_node', right_on='to_node')
```

Then select those that have the same invoice number:

```
columns = ['from_node_x', 'to_node_x', 'value_x', 'from_node_y', 'value_y', 
           'invoice_number_x']

swaps[swaps.invoice_number_x == swaps.invoice_number_y][columns]
#  from_node_x to_node_x  value_x from_node_y  value_y invoice_number_x
#1           B         F       20           X       33                a
#3           D         H       60           X       43                d
#5           E         H       70           A       10                a
```

Comment: Thank you DYZ, a simple and effective answer which is around 3 times faster than mine!